# Dot Net Nuke, custom module addition

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am new to DOT NET NUKE 6.0 and facing a problem. The scene is that I have created a very simple user control in Visual Studio(by using ASP.NET/C#). Now I just want to add it as module in my DNN portal. Task is simple but I don not know how to do. Any help, video link, site is appreciated. I am working in DNN 6.0
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of resources on the DotNetNuke.com site.  Take a look at the wiki entry at http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/module-development.aspx.  It has links to a video series that should be helpful to get started.

If you already have a control, you should make sure that it inherits from `PortalModuleBase`, and use the Extensions module (under Host) to create a new module from the control.  DNN will create the record for it, and even create a test page with the module on it for you.